# ReactElement<any, any> | undefined', but multiple children were provided. Material-UI Fade

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to use a Material UI `<Fade>` component but I keep getting the following error, and I'm fairly new to TypeScript and don't really know how to solve it

```
ReactElement<any, any> | undefined', but multiple children were provided.
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import logo from "./logo.svg"
import "./App.css"
import { Fade } from '@material-ui/core';

interface Game {
  comment: string
  rating: number
}

function App() {
  const [games, setGames] = useState<Game[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/games`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setGames(data))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {games?.map((game) => (
        <Fade in> // error is here in Fade
        <p>{game.comment}</p>
        <p>{game.rating}</p>
        </Fade>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Seems you forgot to put `]` after `setGames`

Comment: thanks, mispasted the code. error still persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fade** only accepts "A single child content element.". Wrap the children inside a fragment.

```
<Fade in>
   <>
      <p>{game.comment}</p>
      <p>{game.rating}</p>
   </>
</Fade>
```